# PHP Simpletest assertion on radio buttons?

Tags: php, unit-testing, simpletest

I have one set of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="edit-status-1" name="status" value="1" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-status-1">Active </label>

<input type="radio" id="edit-status-0" name="status" value="0" checked="checked" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-status-0">Blocked </label>
```

and I want a simpletest to figure out which one is checked by default. I can get to the page, but I don't know how to assert radio buttons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to check in PHP, after the form submission, if the user has checked a different radio input than the default one?

Answer (score 0):

in Zend Framework, when you use zend forms, form->populate($data) get this task done but in pure php you need to compare values :

```
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="0" <?php echo ($_POST['name1']==0):'checked="checked"':'' ?> />
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="1" <?php echo ($_POST['name1']==1):'checked="checked"':'' ?> />
```